# JQuery Loading dynamic content error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamic, load

I want to dynamically load portion of pages inside my index. load() and ajax works but when I click a button in the code I loaded (even if totally empty and without purpose), the page COMPLETELY reload!

What's causing this? I searched for hours and nothing said about this on internet. Am I searching wrong? Or done something wrong?

I used this code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').click(function() {
                $("#dynamic").load("register.php #nicediv");
            }); 
    });
```

Then I used this code:

```
    $('#clickit2').click(function() {
                            $.ajax({
                               url: "register.php",
                               success: function(data){
                                     $( "#dynamic" ).html(data);
                               },
                            });
    });
```

Same results. Please help :(

EDIT:
I found out that problem lies in the form.

if register.php is like this:

```
<form>
<button>push me</button>
</form>
```

then it reloads if I push the button.
Forms can't be dynamically loaded then?

Comment: can you run your program in chrome browser and see if you find any errors in the console of browser. If you have any errors try to fix it, if you are not able to do it, add it here and point out the error.

Comment: The console doesn't find errors...

Comment: You should show a sample of `#dynamic` content.

Comment: @Andrea, check network tab as well, after the click, there will be a call to register.php, see is it successful, if it is successful  and still your are not able to display the data, the problem lies in your  page, post full  page complete js and html/php

Comment: @Andrea: Have a look here : https://css-tricks.com/use-button-element/

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I'd like to use inputs on dynamically loaded forms, there's a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem is on "buttons" and "input type buttons" within forms. Just that.

If you try to load an html file be sure that the buttons exist only outside the form and everything will work smoothly (so far).

Thank you all for the help and I hope this help someone in the future.